# Ubuntu 11.10: how to install OpenJDK 1.7 without OpenJDK 1.6

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10, openjdk

When I install the JRE of OpenJDK 1.7 on Ubuntu 11.10 (or Xubuntu 11.10), it automatically installs OpenJDK 1.6. When now launching `java -version` on the console, version 1.6 is shown. How to install just OpenJDK 1.7 without OpenJDK 1.6?

Comment: I've created a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-access-bridge/+bug/884626

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It installs OpenJDK 1.6 because there is a dependency chain `openjdk-7-jre` -> `libaccess-bridge-java-jni` -> `libaccess-bridge-java` -> `openjdk-6-jre`. Without explicitly breaking the dependencies, there's little you can do here. You should file a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-access-bridge) for the too strict dependency of the `libaccess-bridge-java` package.

In the meantime, you can select which java version should be used with

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```